# Make a div have absolute positioning as well as sticky

Tags: html, css

I want to have a div ("profilemenu") that pops out on the right side of the page with the use of a button (I'll do this myself) with a sticky attribute, but the only way I can position it properly and have it not push the other elements out of order is using position: absolute.

*I tried absolute, it positions the side menu properly but when I scroll, it doesn't stay in place.

I have also tried sticky, but it pushes the other elements out of place.*

I want it to stay on the right side of the page and retain its absolute position even when I scroll down.
**
NOTE: THIS WEBSITE IS ONLY MEANT TO BE RUN ON MOBILE DEVICES. Please inspect the page and select a mobile device on the top left to display it (you probably know this already).**

POP OUT DIV IS NAMED "profilemenu"

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&family=Kanit&family=Orbitron:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Permanent+Marker&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;1,400;1,500;1,600&family=Tourney:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,400,0,0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <title>Foodify</title>
</head>
<div>
    <h1 class="header"></h1>
    <div class="searcharea">
        <div class="location">
            <div class="locationimg"></div>
        </div>
        <input class="searchbar" placeholder="Search for meals or area"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="categories">
        <h2 class="categoriesheader">Top Categories</h2>
        <div class="categoryoptions"><div class="filter"></div>Filter</div>
        <div class="items">
            <div class="itemlist" id="item1"></div>
            <div class="itemlist" id="item2"></div>
            <div class="itemlist" id="item3"></div>
            <div class="itemlist" id="item4"></div>
            <div class="itemlist" id="item5"></div>
            <div class="itemlist" id="item6"></div>  
        </div>
        <div class="itemlistnames">
            <div class="itemlistname">Pizza</div>
            <div class="itemlistname">Burgers</div>
            <div class="itemlistname">Steak</div>
            <div class="itemlistname">Pasta</div>
            <div class="itemlistname">Chicken</div>
            <div class="itemlistname">Rice</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="separator"></div>

    <div class="categories">
        <h2 class="categoriesheader">Popular Items</h2>
        <div class="categoryoptions">View All</div>
        <div class="items">
            <div class="popitemlist">
                <div class="poplistimg" id="poplistimg1"></div>
                <div class="poplistgroup">
                    <div class="poplistheader">Grilled Chicken</div>
                    <div class="poplistprovider">By KFC</div>
                    <div class="poplistprice">Php210</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popitemlist">
                <div class="poplistimg" id="poplistimg2"></div>
                <div class="poplistgroup">
                    <div class="poplistheader">Chicken Joy w/ PMP Meal</div>
                    <div class="poplistprovider">By Jollibee</div>
                    <div class="poplistprice">Php175</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popitemlist">
                <div class="poplistimg" id="poplistimg3"></div>
                <div class="poplistgroup">
                    <div class="poplistheader">Chicken Fillet Ala King Meal</div>
                    <div class="poplistprovider">By McDonald's</div>
                    <div class="poplistprice">Php110</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popitemlist">
                <div class="poplistimg" id="poplistimg4"></div>
                <div class="poplistgroup">
                    <div class="poplistheader">Whopper Meal</div>
                    <div class="poplistprovider">By Burger King</div>
                    <div class="poplistprice">Php230</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="separator"></div>

    <div class="categories">
        <h2 class="categoriesheader">Advertisements</h2>
        <div class="categoryoptions" id="adviewall" onclick="transitionToPage('adpage.html')">View All</div>
        <div class="items">
            <div class="aditemlist">
                <div class="adlistimg" id="adlistimg1"></div>
                <div class="adlistgroup">
                    <div class="adlistheader">Your Ad Here</div>
                    <div class="adlistprovider">Win a free car! Click me for more info</div>
                    <div class="adlistprice">Ad by: Atoyot</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="aditemlist">

                <div class="adlistimg" id="adlistimg2"></div>
                <div class="adlistgroup">
                    <div class="adlistheader">Your Ad Here</div>
                    <div class="adlistprovider">Short Desc.</div>
                    <div class="adlistprice">Ad by: </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="aditemlist">
                <div class="adlistimg" id="adlistimg3"></div>
                <div class="adlistgroup">
                    <div class="adlistheader">Your Ad Here</div>
                    <div class="adlistprovider">Short Desc.</div>
                    <div class="adlistprice">Ad by: </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="aditemlist">
                <div class="adlistimg" id="adlistimg4"></div>
                <div class="adlistgroup">
                    <div class="adlistheader">Your Ad Here</div>
                    <div class="adlistprovider">Short Desc.</div>
                    <div class="adlistprice">Ad by: </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="separator"></div>
    
    <div class="categories" id="adspace">
        <a href="https://www.starbucks.com/"><div class="ad" id="ad1"></div></a>
        <a href="https://www.cocacola.com"><div class="ad" id="ad2"></div></a>
    </div>

    <div class="separator" id="last"></div>


    <div class="footer">
            <div class="footerbutton">
                <div class="footerbuttonicon"></div>
                <div class="footerbuttontext">Explore</div>
            </div>
            <div class="footermenu">
                <div class="cart"></div>
                <div class="account"></div>
            </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="profilemenu">
        <div class="sidemenugroup">
            <div class="profilepic">Picture here</div>
            <div class="profilemanagement">Profile Management</div>
            <div class="accountsettings">Account Settings</div>
            <div class="settings">Settings</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, * {
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .5s;
}

.header {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-style: italic;
    background-image: url(assets/Foodify.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
}

.searcharea {
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: flex-start;
    gap: 15px;
}

.location {
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(170, 170, 170);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 72px;
    row-gap: 10px;
}

.locationimg {
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    background-image: url(assets/marker.png);
    background-size: 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;

}

.searchbar {
    min-width: calc(100% - 135px);
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(170, 170, 170);
    border: none;
    padding: 0px 57px 0px 13px;
    background-image: url('assets/search-icon.png'); 
    background-position: 97% 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Poppins;
}

.searchbar:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.separator {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    border: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.categories {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.categoriesheader {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.categoryoptions {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    left: auto;
    width: fit-content;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
    font-family: Poppins;
}

#adviewall:hover {
    color:#ff8d3a;
    animation-name: rotateviewall;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes rotateviewall {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(90deg)
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(180deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

.filter {
    background-image: url(assets/filter.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 18px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.items {
    margin-top: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    gap: 15px;
    height: fit-content;
}

.items#adpage {
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.itemlist {
    position: inherit;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 80px;
    min-width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(170, 170, 170);
}

.itemlist:hover {
    min-width: 110px;
    height: 90px;
}

.itemlistnames {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    gap: 15px;
    height: fit-content;
}

.itemlistname {
    position: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: fit-content;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#item1 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
}


#item2 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
}

#item3 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
}

#item4 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
}

#item5 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
}
#item6 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
}

.popitemlist {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 120px;
    min-width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(170, 170, 170);
}

.poplistimg {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 80px;
    min-height: 97px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(170, 170, 170);
}

.poplistgroup {
    display: inline-table;
    height: inherit;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.poplistheader {
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    text-wrap: nowrap;
    min-width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}

.poplistprovider {
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
}

.poplistprice {
    margin-top: 35px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#poplistimg1 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 144px;
}

#poplistimg2 {
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url('');
}

#poplistimg3 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
}

#poplistimg4 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
}

.aditemlist {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 170px;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(170, 170, 170);
}

.aditemlist#adpage {
    max-width: 90%;
}

.adlistimg {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 97px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(170, 170, 170);
}

.adlistgroup {
    display: inline-table;
    height: inherit;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px
}

.adlistgroup#adpage {
    margin-left: 5px
}

.adlistheader {
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
}

.adlistprovider {
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
}

.adlistprice {
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: Left;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

#adlistimg1 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 144px;
}

#adlistimg2 {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 144px;
    background-image: url('');
}

#adlistimg3 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 144px;
}

#adlistimg4 {
    background-image: url('');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 144px;
}

.footer {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: #ff8d3a;
    bottom: -1px;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 999999;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

.exploregroup {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.footerbutton {
    position: inherit;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fab98ba6;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 60px;
    padding: 5px 13px 5px 13px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left:30px;
}

.footerbuttontext {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left:8px;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.footerbuttonicon {
    background-image: url(assets/circle-book-open.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
}

.footerbuttonicon#adpage {
    background-image: url(assets/back-icon.png);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.footerbutton:hover {
    animation-name: footerbuttonhover;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes footerbuttonhover {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1, 1)
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1)
    }
}

.footermenu {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 23px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: fit-content;
}

.cart {
    background-image: url(assets/shopping-basket.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
}

.account {
    background-image: url(assets/circle-user.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
}

.profilemenu {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ff8d3a;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 99.5%;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 9998;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

.profilepic {
    position: sticky;
}

.categories#adspace {
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.ad {
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 80%;
    min-height: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#ad1 {
    background-image: url();
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}

#ad2 {
    background-image: url();
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}

#adpage1 {
    background-image: url();
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings:
  'FILL' 0,
  'wght' 400,
  'GRAD' 0,
  'opsz' 24
}
```

[I want the div to stay here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFiN2.png)

[But when I scroll, it, of course, retains its "absolute" position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP4Nz.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you want your `.profilemenu` div not to move while scrolling then you should use `position:fixed;`

Comment: Always welcome @JollyJoe